# Is there any method before email sent to user in Mail::send() - Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have implemented  `Mail::send()` at multiple places in laravel. I have to implement some code before mail is sent. So, I am looking for any method which will be called first before sending email using `Mail::send()` in laravel.

It will save my time to implement new code just before the mail sent.

Comment: You could listen to this event https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mail#events

Comment: @linktoahref thanks for your help. It worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two events to perform to work with. `MessageSending` event gets triggered before the mail is sent and `MessageSent` gets triggered after. These events provide a `Swift_Message` instance of the mail which might come in handy. Create a event listener and attach it to the events to handle them.

```
Illuminate\Mail\Events\MessageSending
Illuminate\Mail\Events\MessageSent
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/mail#events

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/events#defining-listeners